# I want to display a summary like this based on the three tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

My 3 MYSQL tables are as follows:

Table 1: citizen

```
=============================
ID |  Name | Sex    | Address |
=============================
5  | James | Male   | India
6  | Shella|Female  | India
7  | Jan   | Male   | NY
8  | May   | Female | USA
==============================
```

Table 2: benefits

```
========================== 
ID| benefits
==========================
1 | SSS
2 | Coco Life
3 | PhiHealth
4 | Sunlife
==========================
```

Table 3: pensioners

```
============================
ID| benefits_ID | citizen_ID
============================
1 | 1           | 5
2 | 2           | 6
3 | 1           | 7
4 | 4           | 7
==========================
```

I want to display that looks like this:

```
====================================================================
Address | Total Citizen | Male | Female | SSS | Coco Life | Others |
====================================================================
India   | 2             |  1   |  1     |  1  |    1      |   0    |
NY      | 1             |  1   |  0     |  1  |    0      |   1    |
USA     | 1             |  0   |  1     |  0  |    0      |   0    | 
==================================================================
```

Anybody can give me a hint on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `Left Join` from the `Address` table to the `benefits` table, via `pensioners` table, using the appropriate relationships. Left join will allows us to consider a `Address` even when there is no corresponding `benefits` entry for any of its citizens.

In order to count total citizens, male count and female count, you now need to use [`COUNT(DISTINCT ID)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct) after the join. As Joining may create duplicate rows, as a citizen may have more than one benefits.

Also, in order to count "Other" benefits, we need to ensure that the `benefit IS NOT NULL` and it is `NOT IN ('SSS', 'Coco Life')`.

In multi-table queries, it is advisable to use [Aliasing](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/) for Code clarity (readability) and avoiding ambiguous behaviour.

```
SELECT  
  c.Address,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN c.Sex = 'Male' THEN c.ID END) AS male_cnt,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN c.Sex = 'Female' THEN c.ID END) AS female_cnt,
  COUNT(DISTINCT c.ID) AS total_citizen_cnt, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN b.benefits = 'SSS' THEN 1 END) AS SSS_cnt, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN b.benefits = 'Coco Life' THEN 1 END) AS Coco_Life_cnt, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN b.benefits IS NOT NULL AND 
                  b.benefits NOT IN ('SSS', 'Coco Life') THEN 1 END) AS Others_cnt 
FROM citizen AS c 
LEFT JOIN pensioners AS p
  ON p.citizen_ID = c.ID 
LEFT JOIN benefits AS b 
  ON b.ID = p.benefits_ID 
GROUP BY c.Address
```

Comment: Your too quick @Madhur. :D Let me try this piece. Thank you once again.